# Adjustable hats - nice job

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2014

I've noticed something new about the Winter Bash hats. They appear to be doing some facial recognition on the avatar to line the hat elements up with the face. It's most noticeable when the face is tilted.

Did they do this last year, or is it a new feature?

I just wanted to say, well done!

Comment: There's actually a huge warehouse filled with children sitting in front of computers adjusting images of hats onto profiles.

Comment: Oh, they let them sit now?

Comment: I asked a very similar question last year: ["It looks like the front end of the winter bash this year attempts to find the head in the gravatar image, and "fit" the hat to it. The algorithm does an amazing job!"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/211938/175984)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I'm sure somebody will ask again next year too.

Comment: @MarkRansom I agree, unless SO figures out a way to make the adjustment more intuitive, someone inevitably will ask this question next year again.

Comment: Something was said about it [here.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280618/how-are-hats-added-to-the-profile-pictures/280619#comment131441_280619)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

> Did they do this last year, or is it a new feature?

It is a new feature, though... not quite as self adjusting as you think.

---

When selecting a hat, there is a checkbox - "show controls". The controls allow tilting and resizing the hats, so people can adjust them to their avatar.

[image]

Comment: Hah! Since the controls are off by default, and my own avatar is nicely straight and centered, I completely missed them.

Comment: Ha! Great coincidence there :)

Comment: Yep, you're all welcome http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161265/1228 :)

Comment: Well, dammit, now you've made me go and want a hat.

Comment: "show controls" in plain gray letters is about as non-intuitive as it gets. This is what happens when you make programmers design user interface (I run into similar problems more often than I care to admit :-) I would suggest changing this to something less generic and more relevant to the process of fitting a hat to the avatar. Say, "fit your hat", or something similarly blunt.